# Git Log with --first-parent in JetBrains IDEs

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way how to enable `--first-parent`in the log tab of JetBrains git plugin? From command line I would use `git log --first-parent`.

I doubt it is implemented yet.

Comment: Actual Feature Request ticket in JetBrains Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127140

Comment: Vote for it please. ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is no, however `Presentation Settings - Collapse linear branches` gives you a similar view: you still see the first and last commit on each branch, but that does make it easier to see the trunk line.